# laravel app generating an internal server error on shared hosting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to deploy a laravel app on shared hosting. Here is what I did.

I zipped the entire laravel-app directory on my local machine.

I uploaded it and then unzipped the app in the `public_html` folder on the server.

I changed the file permissions of the  `public_html/larvel-app`  and `public_html/laravel-app/storage` and `public_html/laravel-app/public` to `777`.

I removed the line 'public' in the `.gitignore` file.

I then copied the `index.php` and `.htaccess` file from `laravel-app/public` to the homepage and pointed to the necessary autoload folders (the ones about require and the $app variable to `laravel-app/public`).

Problems: If I navigate to my-website homepage, all the HTML for the homepage is being pulled in but no CSS or JavaScript or images. If I navigate to  `my-website/laravel-app/public`, I see an internal server error message (`error 500`). However I have been able to view the files of other folders in the `laravel-app` subdirectory.

I include a  copy of my `.htaccess` file code here.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Look in your logs to see why you are getting an error. `storage/logs/laravel.log` or your web server logs `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: There is nothing in the error log from when the application was deployed.

Comment: If you are getting a 500 error then this **will** be logged. If it isn't in your Laravel log then check your apache log.

Comment: Have you set the appropriate permissions on your `bootstrap/cache` folder?

Comment: ts a shared hosting so I dont have access tp the apache error logs. I think the webmaster does

Comment: @linuxartisan: proper nouns like HTML and JavaScript and CSS do not need bold formatting - just fix the case please. Bold is mainly for emphasis, and should be used sparingly. Otherwise, good edits. Thanks!

Comment: please change your in app.php in config folder , 'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true) . this is set to true to get your detailed errors displayed. Please see if there is laravel.log file in storage/logs if present then see for its content.

Comment: There is none present and the .env file APP_DEBUG is set to true

Comment: Just a side note, if you want to save a lot of time and struggles (like seriously a lot...) then I'd go for Bitbucket + Laravel Forge + DigitalOcean instead of zipping and such. only $15 per month, this gives you version control, no use of ftp (so much safer) and full Laravel functionality support